# Multiple objects subscribing to an NSNotification (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector, nsnotifications

I have an Objective-c class `MyClass` that subscribes to `MyNSNotification`.  There are multiple instances of `MyClass` in my application.  Hence multiple objects receive the notification.  **Is there a way to "filter" notifications for a particular object?**

I imagine doing a check in the selector.  I'm just not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use userInfo for that purpose issuing notification. Recieving one check userInfo to decide if this notification targeted here or not. Sometimes enough to know who sent notification. Use object property for that. Consult class reference http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html